# Почему производители не делают андервольтинг?

Tags: процессор, видеокарта

На форумах оверклокеров часто можно встретить вопросы и статьи про андервольтинг (снижение вольтажа процессора/видеокарты без потери производительности с целью уменьшить мощность и, как следствие, нагрев). Закономерно возникает вопрос — почему производители не делают это сразу, ведь система по-прежнему стабильна? Или это намеренный постепенный вывод техники из строя?

Есть ли вообще какие-либо причины не делать андервольтинг с сохранением стабильности системы, кроме возможных проблем с безопасностью?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что они не дураки. Частоты и напряжения заданные изготовителем стабильны на 99%. Андервольтинг по сути тот же самый разгон, но без поднятия частот, т.к. при разгоне заданные производителем частоты начинают работать на меньших напряжениях.